# What is the reason for answering questions as 'community wiki'?

Tags: support, community-wiki

A [recent answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/87496/38350) was given as a 'community wiki' answer with which I am not familiar.

What is the reason for answering in this way and how does one do so ?

Answer (score 3):

### What is the reason for answering questions as 'community wiki'?

The "community wiki" feature for answers is generally to be used for two reasons, per [wax eagle's answer to "When should an answer be made community wiki?"](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1830/25495)

> - To indicate the answer is incomplete and to invite community contribution to finish it.
> - To avoid gaining reputation for the answer.

[Caleb’s response](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1831/25495) goes onto state the following:

> The "Community Wiki" feature is pretty much a relic of a previous social experiment on the part of Stack Exchange. It wasn't a complete failure, but the lessons they learned from it have mostly gone into other tools and it no longer serves a major primary purpose like it used to. In particular the "comprehensive list" type of thing that it worked for originally is not even an Q&A format we accept right now.

When answering to a post, every individual is given the opportunity to create a community wiki post by checking the "community wiki" box at the bottom right hand corner, just before posting one’s response.

They are great for list questions, which are generally off-topic on Christianity SE.

I do not believe that many of the recent Community Wiki posts are a valid usage of this option.

[Here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/87) is an example of a proper usage of this feature.

Comment: Appreciated. Thank you. I get the impression that some wish to have a voice on Stack Exchange but do not wish to be subject to the way the system actually works in practice.

Comment: @NigelJ I get the same impression, with some network users.